# How to smoothly toggle border-width with jquery?

Tags: jquery-animate

I'm trying to smoothly toggle the border-width of a span between 0 and 5.
This is the code I have tried, developing in firefox

```
    function anim()
    {
     this.sw=!this.sw;
     if(this.sw)
     {
      //lower
      $('.cell_action').animate(
       {
        'border-width':'0px',
        'margin':0
       },
       600
      );
     }
     else
     {
      //raise
      $('.cell_action').animate(
       {
        'border-width':'5px',
        'margin':-5
       },
       600
      );
     }
     }
```

When I try to go to 5px, it seems to work, but when I run the function again to animate back to 0, the border is set immediately to 0 and only the margin animates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems to be a bug...
I'm having the same problem, but noticed the following:

- **FireFox (3):** No animation back to 0
- **Chrome:** No animation back to 0
- **Safari(winXP):** No animation back to 0
- **Opera (10):** No problems. Animates nicely
- **IE (8):** No problems. Animates nicely

Going to investigate further...

**-- EDIT --**

Found the answer on bugs.jquey.com: [ticket 7085](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7085)

> The borderWidth property is a shorthand property and returns a string that is a series of numbers separated by spaces. The .animate() method is only documented to animate properties that are numeric, such as borderLeftWidth.

I fixed my problem by animating to 0px like this:

```
$this.animate({
  borderLeftWidth: "0px",
  borderTopWidth: "0px",
  borderRightWidth: "0px",
  borderBottomWidth: "0px"
}, 200);
```

Comment: Having the same issues in FF.

Comment: Not me... What version are you running??? See this fiddle I whipped up: http://jsfiddle.net/AvanOsch/Kh7DX/5/